# Ruby on Rails: loops and index in object array brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, loops, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Why is it that my index in a loop (in the object array bracket) is not working properly?

```
<% (1..7).each do |i| %>
  <%= select_tag 'hour[day][#{i}]', options_for_select(days_hours) %>
<% end %>
```

Shouldn't `#{i}` become 1, 2, 3, .... 7 in this loop?

```
<%= select_tag 'hour[day][1]', options_for_select(days_hours) %>
<%= select_tag 'hour[day][2]', options_for_select(days_hours) %>
<%= select_tag 'hour[day][3]', options_for_select(days_hours) %>
...
<%= select_tag 'hour[day][7]', options_for_select(days_hours) %>
```

When I check my HTML, it just stays `#{i}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `" "` (double quotes) instead of `' '` (single quotes)

```
<% (1..7).each do |i| %>
  <%= select_tag "hour[day][#{i}]", options_for_select(days_hours) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: that solved the problem! Thanks, didn't know single and double mattered so much. Is there some document talking about when to use single/double quotes?